# Issue with retrieving data from Mysql query

Tags: mysql

The following is my query where I need to get the `parentid` and `id` aliases of specific items categories. However, I currently can only get the id instead of the alias.

The issue which I have is how to get both `parentid` alias and `id` alias with the results. For example, if an item has an id of 2099 and a parent id of 5, I want to get the alias of the matching id and the parent id alias of that matching id.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT a.string, b.id, b.alias ,c.title, c.alias as calias, c.parent_id as pid
        FROM tbl_fields a, tbl__content b ,tbl_categories c
        WHERE a.fields_id='75' AND a.value_string = 'steel' AND a.content_id = b.id AND b.categories_id = c.id
```

My table structure is:

[image]

The results which I want are:

```
City hotel - hotel - appartment
Luxury Hotel - hotel - apartment
```

Comment: That's not related to PHP at all. Plus, syntax errors in SQL

Comment: Add space between "From" and "fields a" use `FROM fields a` instead of `FROMfields a`

Comment: Use explicit join syntax. This code is 1996-era

Comment: Is it always just one hierarchy level or can it be a chain (parent has a parent has a parent)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . only id and parent id belongs to that id... upper levels are no need to consider

Comment: Okay. I posted an answer. Just a side remark: It is often good to use alias names for the tables, as they can enhance readability. The names a, b, and c, however, *lessen* readability. You should always know from the alias names which of the tables they refer to, e.g. f for fields, cat for categories, cont for content. And Drew Pierce is right of course: Please don't use the old error-prone implicit comma-separated join syntax. Use explicit joins, which were introduced in SQL-92, more than twenty years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is just one hierarchy level up you want to see (i.e. no recursion), all you have to do is join the categories table twice:

```
select content.item, cat_parent.alias, cat_self.alias
from content
join categories cat_self on cat_self.id = content.categories_id
join categories cat_parent on cat_parent.id = cat_self.parent_id
where content.id in 
(
  select content_id 
  from fields 
  where fields_id = 75
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add space between "From" and "fields a".

Use

`FROM fields a`

instead of

`FROMfields a`

Comment: thanks i fixed it. the issue which i have is how to get both parent id alias and id alias with the results . please advice Ex: id 2099 parent id is 5 so i want to get the alias of matching id and the parent id alias of that matching id

Answer (score 0):

Rename the string column name. You can not use data type as your column name.

Refer [Naming scheme of database table fields](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22947/A-Naming-Scheme-for-Database-Tables-and-Fields)

Comment: thanks . yes the correct coloumn name is value_string,.. its my type i skipped value part

Comment: the issue which i have is how to get both parent id alias and id alias with the results . please advice Ex: id 2099 parent id is 5 so i want to get the alias of matching id and the parent id alias of that matching id